# How to take the result from a fetch request and insert data into jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, jsx

I am trying to manipulate the request from an api call and insert info into my jsx, but I get this error:

"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

I can see that it has something to do with this my jsx includes a promise, but I dont understand why.

```
import React from "react";

export default function Card_Container() {
  return (
    <div>
      {fetch("http://localhost:1337/posts")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          data.map((post) => {
            return <h1>{post.blogtitle}</h1>;
          });
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the examples in React's documentation: [How can I do data fetching with Hooks?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks)

Comment: Check out my library [suspense-service](https://github.com/patrickroberts/suspense-service) which is built exactly for situations like this, and takes advantage of the relatively new [Suspense API](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html#suspense) that React offers as part of their experimental concurrent mode. The library supports [legacy mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-adoption.html#feature-comparison) as well, so you don't have to enable concurrent mode to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error report, the jsx file can't render a object promise, try to do something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Card_Container() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:1337/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((post) => {
        return <h1>{post.blogtitle}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `useEffect` is triggered once the component has been mounted, when the fetch call receive a response from the server the `setState` will store the information into `data` and the component will be rendered again, but this time if the response is correctly stored into `data` you should see a list of h1 in your application

Answer (score -1):

```
Import React from "react";

export default function Card_Container() {
  return (
    <div>
      { fetch("http://localhost:1337/posts")
         .then((res) => res.json())
         .then((data) => {
          data.map((post => {
            <h1>{post.blogtitle}</h1>
          ))})};
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is not with the logic but syntax. `=>` already works as a return so no need to add another.

**Best Practice:**

```
componentDidMount(){
            console.log(">>>>> componentDidMount...");
            url= 'http://localhost:1337/posts';
            fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
              this.setState({result:responseJson});
              return responseJson;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            });
          }

render() {
              return( 
                <div>
                    {this.state.result.map(post => (
                         <h1>{post.blogtitle}</h1></div>))}
```